# How do I make an object look wet?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

So I started a project and it mainly revolves around a manhole and a street, and it's raining, but I can't get the manhole to look wet.

One thing I tried was to mix 2 noise textures (one with a low scale and one with a high scale), and mix that with the gloss texture, however that barely changes anything.

The Road has puddles on it, ripples, etc. and practically looks pretty wet, however the manhole looks pretty dry, and I can't seem to figure out what to do to fix it.

I thought about making the ripples (made following Gleb Alexandrov's tutorial) affect the manhole too, however I don't know how to make it in a way that looks realistic, as the manhole has a displacement texture, so adding ripples on it wont really fit.

You can see the material for the manhole below, but the node system is huge, so I color-coded everything.

Dark-Blue: Texture Coordinates, Mapping, and Color Ramps

Bright Red: Mix Shader

Dark Red: Overlay Maps (although I don't think they're having much of an effect, so you can ignore them).

Green: Diffuse Stuff (The two textures are the diffuse and the AO map)

White: Reflection

Cyan (sort of): Gloss

[image: Rendered from Viewport]

[image: Viewport]

Comment: The node setup image on the question is very hard to read.

Comment: If you need to share complex node setups I would suggest simplifying your file (remove anything not pertinent to the question) and then uploading it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Have you tried to put the manhole under a water layer ? I mean instead of modifying the manhole material itself. This layer could be made from the video principle but using a glass shader (IOR = 1.3333)

Comment: example : https://i.gyazo.com/c1797158b1eff01090ed0d938dfe814d.png

Comment: would a surface imperfection texture from https://www.poliigon.com/search?category=surface%20imperfections work?

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Basically that is the node setup for the wet material
[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

so that is the result. the darker part is obviously wet.. with some part still holding water that causes reflections :P
i guess it helped... if not.. look for the how to make puddles tutorial by BLENDERGURU