# how to make an object look wet in Eevee? (blender 2.8.3 at least)

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

I was going to answer here [How do I make an object look wet?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57588/how-do-i-make-an-object-look-wet) as it does not specify the rendering engine, but it was closed...

I created a UV Sphere.
Then I used sculpt to make some irregularities to let it shine.
There is 2 lights above, one to the left, other to the right.
Using Principled BSDF (w/o texture).

at Principled BSDF:
Metallic is not what I want, doesnt look wet anyway.
Changing Specular doesnt help, the shine is not sharp/thin.

Comment: Do you just want it shiny, or do you want "puddles"?

Comment: The result I got makes it look wet (no water drops tho), looks also like it is a very polished plastic.

Answer (score 1):

For a very simple, fast and easy to do effect, I just had to:

- In edit mesh mode I used "face/shade smooth", so no need to subdivide the mesh (wouldnt be enough anyway).
- change Roughness to about 0.125, even w/o a texture.

It looks good.
Not sure tho if it could cause trouble later to try to apply other effects (not that I am trying to).
It is only visible in "Viewport shading" "render preview" mode.

Comment: If instead of principled BDSF, I use some shader with texture and normals, I had to change the Specular color to F3F3F3 hexa. I have absolutely no idea how and why it worked, I was just messing with the values until that happened! :). Can someone explain why it worked? I will try to create a .blend test case later.